# HTML/CSS: после transform: translateY(-100%) появилась нижняя граница (скрин)

Tags: html, css, transform

Как убрать то, что я подчеркнул?

[image: Красным подчеркнул появившуюся линию, которую не знаю как убрать]

CSS - transform: translateY(-100%)

Comment: Как убрать то, что я подчеркнул?

Comment: Складывается впечатление что у вас заголовок "Benefis of Odigo" имеет стили display: block; bor-bottom: 1px solid...
Если нет, пришлите код.

Comment: Поднимите не на 100 а на 110%, положение черты изменится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло так: опустил на 90% и линия пропала.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.